# SQL join with criteria on multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, syntax, max, criteria

Can someone please help with syntax for an outer join that has multiple where criteria?  I'm not sure of syntax for overall query and especially not sure how to add criteria to all three tables.

I have three tables:

A: employees (hr_empmstr)

B: benefits (hr_beneinfo)

C: job (hr_emppay)

A:  I need a list of all employees (A).  I need to filter this list to only provide active employees.

B:  For each employee in table A, I need to show current elected benefits (even if none I still need a row) based on current effective dated row in benefits table (B). I was going to do this using something like benefit_end_dt > GETDATE().  This table has multiple rows per employee so A:B is 1:many.

C:  I need to show current job title based on current effective dated row in Job table (C).  This table has multiple rows per employee so A:C is 1:many.

Here is what I have so far but not sure how to add in table C and how to add criteria for all tables (active, latest row, etc...)

```
select a.id, a.name, a.type, a.gender, a.hr_status, b.bene_plan, *
from hr_empmstr a
left outer join hr_beneinfo b
    on a.id = b.id
    and b.bene_end > GETDATE()
```

Tried submitting pics of tables but I don't have enough points :-(

Hope this gives enough info.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what all three tables look like, i.e. what columns they have? That will make it easier for someone to suggest how to perform the joins properly. Just looking at this, I think your first join is wrong because you're using the unique identifiers from both tables rather than foreign & primary keys.

Comment: I am trying to add screen shots of the tables and keys but have no idea how.  Any tips?

Comment: Not sure what OS you're using but you should be able to save the screenshot as an image file and add it to your post by clicking the 'Image' icon when you're editing.

Comment: I found that under edit of my original post, but it won't let me because I don't have enough points on the site...

Comment: I found the PK and FK for each table tho:  beneinfo PK = unique_key, FK = id.  empmstr PK = id, Fk = bargunit.  emppay PK = unique_key, FK = id, pcn.  Hope this helps!

Comment: When I say foreign key, I mean the column that points to the other table. For example, I would expect your ```hr_beneinfo``` table to have a column called ```hr_empmstr_id```, which would correspond to the ```id``` column on the associated ```hr_empstr``` row. Those are the columns that connect the tables together, so those are the columns you would need to join on.

Comment: I have these tables:                                                                               empmstr a PK = id, Fk = bargunit. 
beneinfo b PK = unique_key, FK = id. 
And here is my sql:
select a.id, a.hr_status, a.bdt, a.gender, b.bene_plan
 from empmstr a  
 left outer join beneinfo b
 on a.id = b.id                                                                                                       It is not giving me all from A, it's only giving me people with rows in both. I want to show all in table a and a null field for the field I pull from table B if that employee doesnt exist.

Comment: Two things. 1) The PK and FK info you entered still doesn't tell me what the column names are that we need. It would be easiest if you could update your post to show every column name for each table in question. 2). When you select from 'a' and left join 'b', you'll only get rows where a record exists in table 'a'. If you want rows where 'a' might potentially not exist, you need to use a full join.

Answer (score 0):

If I have 3 tables

```
Table a:

id, name, type, gender, hr_status

Table b:

id, a_id, bene_plan, bene_end

Table c:

id, a_id, title
```

Then I can join them and get relevant information as follows

```
select
  a.*, b.bene_plan, c.job_title
from
  a
left outer join
  b on b.a_id = a.id and b.bene_end > GETDATE()
left outer join
  c on c.a_id = a.id
```

Note that the criteria on `b.bene_end` could also be in a `where` clause.

```
select
  a.*, b.bene_plan, c.job_title
from
  a
left outer join
  b on b.a_id = a.id
left outer join
  c on c.a_id = a.id
 where
   b.bene_and > GETDATE() and
   a.hr_status = 'A'
```

**Update**

If you still want to see entries from `b` when there is no matching `a` record, you could consider doing [full join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-full-joins.htm)

Comment: Ok got that, but how do I add selection criteria to my table A?  I need to limit the type of employees I am pulling to hr_status = 'A', etc...  Where do I add that criteria?  I've tried adding it to the end but it does not work.

Comment: You can add those to the ```where``` clause. I've updated my post to show this.

Comment: Yep got it based on another reply but thank you very much this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your on the right track.

```
 select a.id, a.name, a.type, a.gender, a.hr_status, b.bene_plan, *
 from hr_empmstr a  
 left outer join hr_beneinfo b
 on a.id = b.id
 left outer join hr_emppay c
 on a.id = c.id
 where b.bene_end > GETDATE() and c.job > GETDATE()
```

Assuming you have an active employee flag someplace, like hr_status, in your where statement add an AND a.hr_status = 'what ever your active flag is' 
this should bring everything from the two tables.

Comment: The only problem here I think is the keys you're joining on.  We should be using the unique identifiers for both tables in a join, but rather the foreign/primary keys of the respective tables.

Comment: YES this was what I needed! I tried adding criteria to the end before but must have had the wrong syntax.  I used this statement and added an additional criteria from table A and it worked.

Comment: THANK YOU!  And thank you to everyone else for your quick responses and genius minds!

Comment: Would using the PK/FK resolve not showing at least one row for everyone?  Here is the query I am using now:                                              select a.id, a.name, a.hr_status,a.bdt, a.gender, d.long_desc, c.actl_hrly * 2080 as Salary, b.bene_plan--, *
 from hr_empmstr a  
 left outer join hr_beneinfo b
 on a.id = b.id
 left outer join hr_emppay c
 on a.id = c.id
 left outer join hr_pcntble d
 on c.pcn = d.pcn
 where b.bene_end > GETDATE() 
 and c.pay_end > GETDATE()
 and d.effend > GETDATE()
 and a.type like 'FT%'
 and a.hr_status = 'A'

Answer (score 0):

We don't have your bd structure, so if we assume that :

1 : for each A record, there is only one b records with bene_end greater to GetDate()

2 : We have a field "IsCurrent" in table c

Then the following query will work :

```
SELECT  *
FROM hr_empmstr
LEFT JOIN  hr_beneinfo  ON hr_empmstr.id =  hr_beneinfo.id
                        AND hr_beneinfo.bene_end > GETDATE()
LEFT JOIN hr_emppay     ON hr_empmstr.id = hr_emppay.id
                        --AND hr_emppay.IsCurrent = 1
WHERE hr_empmstr.hr_status = 'A'
```

If assumption are false, then you could trim down the one to many relationship to 1:1 using a subquery in the join. 
This give this :

```
SELECT  *
FROM hr_empmstr
LEFT JOIN  hr_beneinfo  ON hr_empmstr.id =  hr_beneinfo.id
                        AND hr_beneinfo.unique_key = (SELECT TOP 1 B.unique_key
                                                      FROM hr_beneinfo AS B
                                                      WHERE B.id = hr_empmstr.id
                                                      ORDER BY bene_end DESC)
LEFT JOIN hr_emppay     ON hr_empmstr.id = hr_emppay.id
                        AND hr_emppay.unique_key = (SELECT TOP 1 C.unique_key
                                                    FROM hr_emppay AS C
                                                    WHERE C.id = hr_empmstr.id
                                                    ORDER BY DateFieldToReachLatest DESC)
WHERE hr_empmstr.hr_status = 'A'
```

Another solution would be to use a CROSSJOIN on a QUERY that trim down record to 1:1.

I can't comment(Not enough point) :

To show us your DB structure, you can right click on your table in SQL Management Studio and click "Script as" -> "Create to". Then copy paste the generated script in your question.

Comment: 1.  B table holds many rows per row in A: its a one to many relationship.  For every one employee, they may have no benefit rows, one active benefit row or many active benefit rows.  Example for me:  I am enrolled in medical, dental, vision so I would show up with at least three active rows.

Comment: When retreiving an employee, you want all the benefit as well or just the last one? Same question for JobTitle.

Comment: I want all active benefits (which may be multiple rows) and the single active job (latest effective date).

Comment: I tried doing the Script As > Create to but we are a hosted solution and apparently I don't have access rights to do that function.  Another reply answered my original question so thank you very much for all your help!